# Protractor: Does both controlled enabled flow and control disabled flow can work together in protractor till moving to control disabled flow.?

Tags: protractor

I am trying to understand the scope of control enabled and disabled flow in one automation project of protractor. For example: If we 10 functions in one test case if we have 9 functions with promise handling(i.e then()) and if we have 1 function with async await enabled then will the test case work? With this what should be the state of SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER?

Please shed some light on this kind of architecture, will this still work robust?
Because, handling promise is becoming difficult for me in long run, so i am planning to change the approach with async await.. But want to understand can we still manage the project deliverables with this partial transition?

Comment: https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await i think its answered here. But why would you want to mix those? essentially this is your code styling, and you should adhere to one. Moreover, afaik `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` has no effect starting from protractor 6

Comment: Thank you Sergey, I forgot to mention the link which you pointed. I went through. Also the GitHub issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3037 if you observe, in one function they are trying to implement both which is not accepted. I have framework built on promises, which is becoming difficult to manage, because test case organizing has to be compromised on.

Comment: Also, the need for me to mix, is all files at a time I cannot replace so want to replace file by file, keeping deliverables in mind.

Comment: Where I was facing issue with promises is fetch() functions are pending longer. And I need to fetch 7 times with dynamic request, so which is going too much asynchronous, wanted to fix this with hope of async/await.

Comment: I didn't understand this point of yours.SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER has no effect starting from protractor 6

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969 plan for removing SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER from protractor. According, to its phase 3, `The SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER environment variable will no longer have any effect`